# Paginator Number of Pages does not update in HTML after filtering results - Django

Tags: html, django, pagination

Paginator Number of Pages does not update in HTML after filtering with django_filter.

**html file**

```
<span>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
```

The `page_obj.paginator.num_pages` is the initial number (without any filters) of all results in the table (example: I got 12 results and showing 3 results/page => 4 pages)

**views**

```
class SearchBookView(ListView):
    template_name = "booksearch.html"
    paginate_by = 3
    model = Book

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    book_qs = Book.objects.all()
    book_filter = BookFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=book_qs)
    paginator = Paginator(book_filter.qs, self.paginate_by)

    print(paginator.num_pages) ### Prints the correct num pages everytime even after filtering

    page = self.request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        book_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        book_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        book_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context['book_list'] = book_list
    context['book_filter'] = book_filter
    return context
```

After adding a filter (let's say after filtering it shows 5 results) `page_obj.paginator.num_pages` should be 2 in my HTML, right? Although in my view in `print(paginator.num_pages)` it shows 2, in the HTML it stays the original 4 pages. How can I pass this to the HTML file?

**EDIT**

**filters**

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    category = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        ields = ['name', 'author', 'category',]
```

**full html**

```
<h1 class="h1"> Search Books </h1>
<form method="get">
    {{ book_filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for book in book_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.category }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li>
                <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
            <li class="">
                <span>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
            </li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li>
                <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No books available</p>
        {% endif %}
</div>
```

**WORKAROUND**

I did a workaround but it is kind of ugly:

in my **view** I added a `context['num_pages'] = paginator.num_pages` and pass it my **HTML**:

```
<span>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ num_pages }}.</span>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this the correct way without adding a new context key, value pair?

Comment: What do you mean "After adding a filter" ?

Comment: Added an Edit update with full HTML and Filter class. A Filter returns the results of a custom query set (example I want to display results with all the books that are in the "Fiction" category). Hopefully, I am able to explain as I am new to Py and Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the queryset in the `get_queryset` method.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    book_qs = Book.objects.all()
    self.book_filter = BookFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=book_qs)
    return book_filter.qs
```

Django will take care of paginating the queryset, and all you need to do in `get_context_data` is add `book_filter` to the context.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['book_filter'] = self.book_filter
    return context
```